# iphone: custom UITableViewCell taller than the default cell view

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm creating an application that consists of a ListView with 5 rows:
- 1st one containing a graph
- 2nd to 5th rows containing some data with the same formatting.

I have created 2 classes: GraphCustomViewCell and DataCustomViewCell.
Depending upon the position of the cell I load the correct CustomCell with:

```
NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"GraphCustomViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];               
for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
{
    if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[GraphCustomViewCell class]])
    {
        cell = (GraphCustomViewCell *)currentObject;
        break;
    }
}
```

That works fine except that the first row, the one corresponding to the graph, is bigger (in height) that the 4 other rows, and as a results it hides the 3 first other rows.

Is there any option in the table view that enables the custom cell to expand the default cells ?
I'd like that the 5 rows (graph + 4 data rows) to fit the entire screen (480 - tabbar's height).

Thanks a lot for your help.
Regards,
Luc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement [heightForRowAtIndexPath:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:) in your delegate.